# IMPALA: RIGHT OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node

Tags: query-optimization, impala

I have enabled stats using `COMPUTE STATS` on a table. After this when I re-run the query, it's giving me an error `A RIGHT OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan`. Dropping the stats is executing the query. I'm trying to improve the query performance.  I’m new to impala and trying to understand how COMPUTE STATS causing a join issue.

Note: My query has a left join and doesn’t have a right join.

```
Select f1, f2, f3 from (
     Select t.t1, t.t2, t.t3 from table1 t
     Left join
     Select p.p1, p.p2, p.p3 from table2 p on p.p1=t.t1) i
Where condition
```